# Why can't I use self in a func Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to self to add SKSpriteNodes to the view in a function, but Xcode will not allow me to do so. It gives me the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'self'"

```
 func indicate() {
if test == 0 {
    var large = ((CGFloat(largest)*54) - 29) - selectedNode.position.x
    var small = selectedNode.position.x - ((CGFloat(smallest)*54) - 29)

    indicatorRight.position = CGPointMake(selectedNode.position.x + large, selectedNode.position.y)
    indicatorRight.userInteractionEnabled = true
    indicatorRight.zPosition = 0.5

    indicatorLeft.position = CGPointMake(selectedNode.position.x - small, selectedNode.position.y)
    indicatorLeft.userInteractionEnabled = true
    indicatorLeft.zPosition = 0.5


    println(indicatorLeft.position)
    //  println(smallest)
    self.addChild(indicatorRight)
    self.addChild(indicatorLeft)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 18):

Make sure the method is presented in the Class open and closing braces

class A
{

// You need to define a method here

}

// You might have declared it here.

Answer (score 6):

Nas,

For a func to be able to use "self", it needs to be part of a class.

"self" refers to the current instance upon which a method (or in Swift parlance: "func") is applied. If a func is defined at global level, then if is *not* part of a class, therefore it cannot be associated with an instance of a class.

Hence the impossibility to use 'self" in that context.